# operator and function precedence in Haskell

Tags: function, haskell, operator-keyword, infix-notation, operator-precedence

So this does not work:

```
take 50 iterate (* 2) 1
```

Because it requires parenthesis in the second argument of take. My question is why.

Haskell rightfully sees a discrepancy in the types:

```
 Couldn't match expected type `[a0]'
            with actual type (a1 -> a1) -> a1 -> [a1]'
```

My questions are:

1) It seems that haskell first tries to resolve the take 50 function before the iterate function. Why does haskell do this? When in mathematics if you have f g t w u (x) you first evaluate u(x) before doing anything else. Why does haskell start with evaluating f in this case?

2) Haskell was smart enough to detect that the actual type was:

```
(a1 -> a1) -> a1 -> [a1]
```

Now, if it sees that the output of this function is [a1], a type that would unify with the expected type [a0], why does haskell not unify it?

3) why does the $ operator fix this? I know that:

```
($) :: (a -> b) -> a -> b
```

So basically what this operator does is say "write FUNCTION $ ARGUMENT" and you get the value of the function evaluated at that argument.  In the take 50 case the type is:

```
take 50 :: [a2]->[a2]
take 50 $ :: a->b 
where a ~a2 and b~b2 then
take 50 $ :: [a2]->[a2]
```

So basically im in the same situation as in the first case, without using parenthesis or $. This case is i need an argument of the type [a2] (haskell calls it [a0] but its the same. So.. why does haskell unify [a2] with (a1 -> a1) -> a1 -> [a1] when i use $ but it doesnt when i dont use it?

Comment: "When in mathematics if you have f g t w u (x) you first evaluate u(x) before doing anything else." Eh... no? Juxtaposition often means multiplication in maths, while it's function application in Haskell. Do you have a better example?

Comment: i meant function composition, the keyboard does not have the function composition symbol used in mathematics, although i agree i couldve used the dot to imply composition.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Function application (denoted by "juxtaposition", putting a function and its argument next to each other) has to be parsed somehow, and it needs to be either left-associative or right-associative in order to be parsed unambiguously.<sup>1</sup>

Function application is actually left-associative, so what you wrote is equivalent to

```
((((take 50) iterate) (* 2)) 1)
```

If it were right-associative instead, you would have

```
(take (50 (iterate ((* 2) 1))))
```

That's not what you wanted either, and it's much worse as a default choice: there are very few programs where a right-associative operator would feel more natural.

Since no uniform rule for parsing can produce the program you intend, it's necessary for you, the programmer, to tell haskell what you actually meant, by giving a hint in the form of `$` or some parentheses.

As for why `$` helps: it is defined to have a very low precedence in parsing, so that writing

```
take 50 $ iterate (* 2) 1
```

parses as

```
(take 50) $ ((iterate (* 2)) 1))
```

which is actually what you wanted.

<sup>1</sup> Unambiguous parsing is a very desirable property for having understandable programs, and letting the typechecker decide how to parse things (as you suggest it might be able to do) would be quite a mess.

Comment: Thanks, very well explained.

Answer (score 5):

`f g t w u (x)` is not a sequence of function applications in math either. However, in math, if we take `.` to be the function composition operator, then `(f . g . t . w . u) (x)` first applies the `u` function then the `w` function and so on. This is the same in Haskell: `(f . g . t . w . u) x`.

In your first type error, it is trying to unify the type `[a0]` with the type `(a1 -> a1) -> a1 -> [a1]`, not with the type `[a1]`. It isn't possible for this to unify, so it gives an error.

Juxtaposition is function *application* in Haskell, not function composition (incidentally, in math juxtaposition is usually multiplication). This means that an expression like `f x y z` means (essentially) "apply the function `f` to the arguments `x`, `y` and `z`". This is equivalent to `((f x) y) z`. Each function in Haskell takes exactly one argument. What this means is that something like `f x y z = x + y * z` is actually the same as `f = \x -> \y -> \z -> x + y * z`. Function application is left associative so `f x y z` is the same as writing `((f x) y) z`, that is, apply `f` to `x` first take the resulting function and apply that to `y`. Finally, apply that function to `z`.

This means that your original expression is interpreted as (again, converting to standard math notation): `take(50, iterate, (* 2), 1)`.

Comment: `f x y z` is *not* equivalent to `f(x,y,z)`. It is equivalent to `((f  x) y) z`. All functions in Haskell take a single argument.

Comment: @ReinHenrichs I know, but I didn't feel that was relevant to add at this point. That's why I said "essentially."

Comment: It's certainly relevant to explain function application correctly when answering a question about how function application works!

Comment: @ReinHenrichs I was just creating a simpler analogue to standard math notation, so things wouldn't get too confused. In my opinion, it is easier to understand things in this way first and then learn how it *really* works (this is how a lot of things are learned anyway. You don't learn about imaginary numbers when you learn about square roots.)

Comment: @ReinHenrichs I added a note about that. If you feel that it should be further expanded upon, let me know. Also, I would argue that it isn't even *necessarily* wrong, depending on what we understand that math notation to mean. Maybe it can be partial application.

Comment: I think any claim that `f x y z` is like `f(x, y, z)`, now matter how carefully qualified, is incorrect and should be removed. `f x y z = ((f x) y) z`. If you want to define `f(x, y , z) = ((f x) y) z`, why not just use `((f x) y) z`? You don't need to misuse an existing notation and there's no possibility of being misunderstood if you do so.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52340/discussion-between-david-young-and-rein-henrichs)

Answer (score 2):

`take 50 iterate (* 2) 1` would be equivalent in languages with parenthesized-calls with `take (50, iterate, * 2, 1)`, but what you want is `take (50, iterate(* 2, 1))`. The `$` serves exactly the purpose of "open a parenthesis here and close it the most far you can". Its just like calling a function, but right-associative instead of left-associative. You can write it without the `$` operator using `take 50 (iterate (*2) 1)`.

Comment: `$` isn't really about parentheses. Any other infix operator will have the same "grouping" effect here (because there are no other infix operators involved, so the precedence doesn't matter), i.e. `take 50 + iterate (* 2) 1` will also force `take 50` and `iterate (* 2) 1` to be two separate expressions, so that `(* 2)` and `1` are seen as arguments to `iterate` rather than more arguments to `take`. Obviously that will be a type error, but what distinguishes `$` from `+` here isn't the "grouping", it's the meaning of "apply left argument to right argument".

Answer (score 1):

Function application is left associative, so

```
f g a b
```

is

```
((f g) a) b
```

So you have

```
(((take 50) iterate) (*2)) 1
```

This is incorrect since it applies `take 50 :: [a] -> [a]` to `iterate` which has the type `(a -> a) -> a -> [a]`, clearly incorrect.

Comment: @user3558296 If I've answered you're question, feel free to accept my answer with that check mark :)

Answer (score 0):

(I'll give you a little bit more verbose answer, covering some corners that I think other answers left uncovered, not explicitly at least).

In Haskell, **parentheses do *not* signify function call**. They are just for grouping. So `u (x)` is exactly the same as `u x`, in Haskell.

The type error you first show is generated by Haskell trying to use `iterate` as the 2nd argument to `take`:

```
take    :: Int -> [a0]                     -> [a0]
take       50     iterate                  :: t 
iterate ::        (a1 -> a1) -> a1 -> [a1]
                  ------------------------
                  [](...) and (->)(...) do not match
```

It doesn't try to "resolve `iterate` function after having resolved `take 50` function". It hasn't looked at the rest of your long expression yet. It's just trying to use the `iterate` *value*. Which happens to be a function.

Functions are just values in Haskell, that's why there's no special syntax for calling them, like there is in various `foo(args){exps;};` languages.

For a compiler to try to correct your expressions for you is too dangerous: too many typos or errors would suddenly get unintended meanings. At the most this could be a feature of some hypothetical interactive development environment.

When you write `take 50 $ iterate (*2) 1`, the type of that second expression (after the `$` operator) is

```
iterate ::        (a1 -> a1) -> a1 -> [a1]
iterate           (*2)          1  :: [Int]  -- it's actually (Num a => [a]) 
                                             -- but that's besides the point
```

and that *list-of-numbers* type (`:: Num a => [a]`) is what gets matched against the 2nd argument in the call to `take`, *not the type of naked non-applied `iterate` itself*:

```
take    :: Int ->               [a0]       -> [a0]
take       50     (iterate (*2) 1  )       :: t 
iterate (*2) 1    :: (Num a) => [a ]
                  ------------------
                  a0 ~ (Num a)=> a            t ~ (Num a) => [a]
```

And so it *"typechecks"*, i.e. it works. And indeed, in GHCi we get

> Prelude> :t take       50     (iterate (*2) 1  ) 
>       take       50     (iterate (*2) 1  ) ::           (Num a) => [a]